# How to set height of row in ListView DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

### Question

How can I increase the height of each row in my DataTemplate. I've set the height multiple times in different elements, however the row height doesn't change from the seemingly default height.

What am I missing?

### Xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListViewItems">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" Height="400">
                            <Grid Padding="5" Margin="5" HeightRequest="400">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Image Source="@drawable/cereals.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="400" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try setting HasUnevenRows="True" on the ListView

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to allow a ListView row to set its own height, you need to set the ListView HasUnevenRows property to true.

Comment: ListView has 2 ways to set the row height. One way is to set ListView.RowHeight then every row has the same height. If the rows each need a different height then set HasUnevenRows to true then each row height will be calculated by the content of the row. Be aware that this is slower to render.

Answer (score 4):

Just put HasUnevenRows="True"
on the ListView. This should do the trick.